# Extra spaces in the end while retrieving CHAR values

Tags: java, oracle, char, ibatis, spaces

I am using ibatis and oracle 10. The jdbc driver is oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. When I retrieve data from table, I found two spaces '  ' are appended. Let's say column ACTIVE_IND CHAR(1), the data retrieved is 'A  '.

Please note that this is happening for all the CHAR fields. And no of extra spaces is always two times the length of CHAR. For example, if there is a column of CHAR(14), no of extra spaces in the end are 28.

This is happening in the System Testing environment only. In our local desktops, using the same ojdbc14.jar and same code, we did not get any extra spaces.

I think the only thing different in System Testing environment is database. Is it related to some character encoding? Do we have some configuration in database to change it?

Comment: Oracle can store 1-byte character sets or multibyte character sets. CHAR(1) is no longer descriptive enough... is that CHAR(1 CHAR) or CHAR(1 BYTES). If the answer is the first and the character set is defined as 2 bytes then the space allocated is two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very like a character encoding issue. Have you checked

1. the configuration of the Oracle db in each case
2. what character encoding your app is running under for each environment (you can configure this using `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` or similar - I would strongly recommend this)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be completely determined from the information you gave what exactly went wrong. As far as the encoding for a column is concerned it is affected by the COLLATION SETTING. You can check the following link for more information: http://www.lessanvaezi.com/collation-in-oracle-using-nls_sort/